# Can't insert single row in Excel spreadsheet in a VBA loop

Tags: vba

The following code should insert a single row between every 5th row of my spreadsheet but instead inserts 5 blank rows. Single stepping shows that when the Rows(i).select is executed, it selects 5 rows and then does the insert. Very simple code below:

```vb
for i = 126 to 1 step -5
   Rows(i).Select
   Selection.Insert Shift := xlDown
next i
```

Comment: This works fine for me, not sure why it's not working for you. I've seen some bizarre Excel behavior in the past when I had a bunch of pending Office updates. Installing them and rebooting fixed the issue for me - see if that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the select command. If the corresponding cells are merged, as many rows as the merged cells are inserted.

```
Sub test()
    For i = 126 To 1 Step -5
        'Rows(i).Select
        Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next i
End Sub
```

### Original image if there are merged cells on the sheet

[image]

### Resut of your code

[image]

### Resut of my code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your code is running well- it does insert blank row after the 5th row, however, your code will insert row on the first loop right after the first row before it will insert blank row after the 5th row. You may try this code

```
For i = 6 To 126 Step 5
   Rows(i).Select
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Next i
```

or if you want to start from the bottom

```
   For i = 122 To 1 Step -5
       Rows(i).Select
       Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next i
```

I started from row 6 since row 1 is a header. Then it will start inserting blank row every after the 5th row.